# Getting 'Date' Value from Android Material CalendarView into Database

Tags: android, database, calendar, calendarview

I'm learning how to program by making an Android app. I've got the Material CalendarView library.

What I want to do is that when I click on a date it loads information stored in the date from the database.

What I don't understand is, how do I add the 'date' value into my SQL so that each date can create a new row in my database.

content_main.xml:

```
    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mcv_firstDayOfWeek="monday"
    app:mcv_tileWidth="match_parent"
    app:mcv_tileHeight="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/calendar">

</com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView>
```

MainActivity:

```
        MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    materialCalendarView.state().edit()
            .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.MONTHS)
            .commit();
```

I've got ListView which loads on the click of any date. I want this list view to be populated by the relevant data for that day.

```
        materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {

            //ListView starts here
            mSalahList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.salahListView);
            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), salahList);
            mSalahList.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use for getting the calendar working?

Comment: I've updated my OP with the code.